# How to cast a java.util.HashMap$Node object?

Tags: java

I use a library method which returns a `java.util.HashMap$Node` object.
I have tried to cast it to `Map`, `HashMap`, or `Iterator` but they have all failed.
To what data type I can cast an object of type `java.util.HashMap$Node`?

Comment: You can't cast it to anything else since it's *not* any of those classes.  It's an internal `Node` type which happens to live inside of `HashMap`.  I'm stunned you're able to get it *at all* since [that class is package-private](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/HashMap.java?av=f#278).

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why would you want to do that, and how did you get access to an object of an internal type in the first place?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What is the purpose of the library you are using? What do you want to do with the `Node` object? Casting is the wrong solution here. If you explain what you want to accomplish, then we can help you to find a correct solution.

Comment: @Clashsoft you can see the class through the debugger. One legitimate reason for the library to return a `HashMap.Node` instance is if the method actually returns `Object` and does not/cannot use generics.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HashMap.Node` implements `Map.Entry`, so you can cast to that.

Comment: Since it’s an internal class, this can change in future Java releases.  It is not a good idea to rely on this.

Comment: @VGR it depends, the use case I'm considering is that the library in question returns plain `Object` and doesn't use generics (as `Map.get` could), so `Map.Entry` could be a valid return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can only cast an object to one of its base classes or interfaces. You are unable to cast `java.util.HashMap$Node` to any of the classes or interfaces which you have tried because it does not extend any of them.

I find it very strange that the library you use returns objects of this type since it is an internal implementation detail of `HashMap`. I suggest that you either modify the library, if you have access to the source code, or find a different library to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was getting java.util.HashMap$Node, which I can't cast or do anything with other than reading the data because I forgot to add Optional when collecting list of optional. Objet is a map.

Changed

```
Map<String, List<Object>>
```

to

```
Map<String, List<Optiona<Object>>>
```

and now I can get the actual maps and not java.util.HashMap$Node.